# Why is my Google Analytics profile filter not showing pageviews for separate domain?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have a GA setup of one main domain, plus subdomains, plus a separate Tumblr domain. I am trying to get a filter to work for the Tumblr. I can see pageviews in the real-time at the main domain level showing for Tumblr hits, but not in the profile filter, which leads me to believe I have a problem in my filter setup.

**Main reporting GA URL:**

```
 - example.com
```

GA code on the main domain is:

```
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-XXXXXXX-1');
  pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
  pageTracker._setDomainName('none');
  pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

**Blog filter URLs:**

```
 - blog.example.com
 - example.tumblr.com
```

The GA code on the Tumblr is:

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.tumblr.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

I have a profile called "blog" which has two custom filters:

```
  Include / Hostname / "blog\.example\.com"
  Include / Hostname / "tumblr"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Instead of having two include filters for the blog profile, I needed to only have one, and use an OR pipe to include both:

```
tumblr|blog\.example\.com
```

Having two separate filters was causing them to cancel each other out.